# Fixing the disc reader on an SCPH-30001 NTSC-U/C model PlayStation 2

Tags: hardware, ps2

I have attempted to fix the infamous disc reader error on my fat SCPH-30001 NTSC-U/C PlayStation 2. I have gotten into the disc drive to adjust the calibration (white) wheel (4 clicks at a time) all the way around but I still am getting the error. **I noticed that the calibration (white) wheel reset itself to it's default location when I opened it up after moving it to a new location to fix the disc reader error.** A few people suggested flipping the console, but I'm worried that it could affect the disc or hardware. People like GameSack have suggested that for the PlayStation 1 to get rid of heat so it could be possible. Anything else I should try and possibly fix it from resetting like that? [My Calibration (White) Wheel Reset Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLm32DHseiU)

Comment: "Listing all the possible fixes" sends up massive red flares regarding the broadness of the answer you are seeking. Relative to your specific problem, a good answer could be quite detailed, but asking for all the possible fixes to create a detailed canonical answer? I could be wrong.. but I think you might want a hardware-based site, to reach an appropriate audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a lot of suggestions as Timelord64 suggested, but here's a simple guide that has a clear suggestion.

http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2003/11/ps2-repair-guide/3/

The guide starts with taking a part the PS2 on the first 2 pages, so I am guessing you are past that (since you can see the gear).  Also in the guide it appears to be a PS2 that's similar to yours, a model SCPH-30001 Playstation 2, with a U serial number (not sure about your serial number).

```
 Plug just one controller into the front of your PS2. With the lens at the bottom position,
put a game in the tray. Start with your PSone game. Place the black lid on top of the tray
and lightly but firmly hold it down. Too hard and your game will click as it tries to spin,
too light and the lid will fly off!

 You can also leave a light paperweight on top of the lid

 Plug your PS2 back in and turn it on. The tray should close. Let's turn on the TV and see
if it works!

 After the splash screen, hit X to open the browser. Now we get to wait and see whether it
loads!

 With any luck, it will load at least one of your games. That's great, but we picked out
four different titles for a reason! I tried them one-by-one in this order: PSone, DVD,
Silver PS2, and Blue PS2. The Blue is the most difficult, so after you get your first
successful load, you may want to start with it instead of a PSone game.

 If at least one of your discs doesn't load, don't fret. Eject your disc and unplug the PS2
with the tray open. Take the black lid off and let's look at that gear again. Turn the gear
clockwise four clicks ? about 1/8th of a full turn. Pop the game in, put the lid back on,
and try again. Repeat this until the games all show up in the browser window. Remember to
turn the PS2 off between tries, as there's a class 1 laser in there.
```

That's the important part that has a clear suggestion how to figure out the calibration.  So basically you turn the gear until it resets to the bottom, try the CD, possibly a game you don't care for (in case the CD gets damaged), then turn the gear 4 clicks or about 1/8th of a turn every time it doesn't work.  It may be difficult to tell if it's working if you don't have all 4 CDs they suggest, but worst case you have to open it up later and adjust it again.

**PARTS**

In this case, after looking at your youtube video, it appears it isn't just a simple calibration, and will need some parts replaced.

You will need to make sure to find out if the parts are compatible with your version (3000x in this case), but here are some parts you can replace.

1. Spindle Drive motor - this is fairly cheap, there's no clear indicator when it's going out, but this turns the gear that moves the laser assembly to read each different type of CD.
   Not sure if the picture shows any from a 3000x
   [image: Drive Motor]
2. Drive Snake/Worm motor - This motor controls the laser going back and forth, and can cause a grinding/ticking noise if this is the plastic piece touching it (attached to laser) is broke.
   [image: Drive Snake motor]
3. Laser Lens - This can be replaced if the lens itself is not working correctly, but the rest of the drive is.  There isn't a good way to tell if this is going bad either.
   [image: Laser Lens]
4. Calibration Gear/Motor - If any teeth are broken or missing, you will need to replace the gear.  There is a small flat area that is the same length as the teeth.  The motor is next to it, and may need replaced.  The motor may not have an indication it's bad unless it's grinding on the gear (one or both will need to be replaced then).
   [image: Calibration Gear]

I think the Calibration Motor (may have another name) is most likely what you need to find.  If there's a problem with the motor, you will have to replace it to find out.  Otherwise the other 2 parts would be the snake/worm motor and/or the white plastic piece touching it.  Lastly the lens, but that should be all of the main parts in the assembly, most of which you can find on Ebay or any repair shop/website that repairs PS2s.  Just make sure you ask before you buy that it is for the 3000x model, and that you can see a picture of it and compare with the one on your PS2.

Comment: My Calibration (White) Wheel Reset Problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLm32DHseiU

Comment: That looks like another part in the drive isn't working.  Have you looked at replacing the whole disc drive?

Comment: Is there a way to get a fully working disc drive for the PS2 on eBay?

Comment: To clarify, OP is asking that **we detail all suggestions**.

Comment: If possible m8 ^

Comment: @Timelord64 That's why i'm asking if they have looked at replacing the whole drive.  They are asking for all suggestions, but their situation was different from what I was thinking from their question.  Otherwise that guide would have worked for a normal situation where he just needs to calibrate the laser, but looking at the video it's pretty clear there are other parts inside the drive not working correctly.  If he had replaced the drive and still had the same problem, i would want to know that before making another edit on my answer, otherwise there isn't much i can suggest (I.E. new PS2).

Comment: Honestly, I think thos question would have been closed as too broad, if it did not have a bounty

Comment: @CamouflagedCow I added more information about the parts to give you an idea what to replace for the drive assembly.  Hopefully it helps you, and good luck finding the parts.

Comment: Since this is the only answer and detailed, have some rep.

Answer (score -1):

personally id recomend you to look into a program called freehdboot...it is freemcboot for a harddrive. for $6 I got a usb to sata cable on ebay and had several sata drives laying around with a little tinkering and research you can br launching games from the drive instead of from your disk cutting load times down to nothing and bypassing your drive troubles....

that said you can still buy whole ps2's from gamestop so I would presume you could get a repair/ replacement from them. A quick google search showed some for apx $7 from different sources.

There is a chance you would be stuck with the options of replacing the drive oy maybe you could replace the pot that sounds like may be damaged with something you have laying around presuming it is compatible and your solider skills are up to par....

of course this is still presuming that it is just a mal adjustment issue and not a totally spent laser head which again would need replaced to fix...