# What is the reference of this PlayStation 2 disk motor?

Tags: hardware, ps2, hardware-identification

I have to change the motor of a PS2 but the only ones I find that looks the same have the wrong ribbon, and they don't fit properly.
I can't find any seller on eBay or elsewhere that have this motor with the right ribbon.
Do you have an idea of the exact reference of this set of motor/ribbon or where I could search for it?

Here are pics of my PS2 drive motor:
[image: Pic1] [image: Pic2]
[image: Pic3]

In [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/250728/211518) we can see different motors and their ribbons, and as you can see the motor of my PS2 looks like the one at the right but the ribbon is different.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 main things used to define a ribbon cable: length, number of conductors, and pitch (distance between each conductor).  For most uses, the length is the least important aspect, it just needs to be long enough.  If you get a replacement part that has the same cable, but just longer, then it should just work assuming you have enough space to squeeze it in.  If it's not long enough, but has the right pitch and number of wires, you can still remove the original cable and solder it to the new motor.  If it doesn't have the right pitch, you can splice a bit of the old cable onto the new cable (just be careful to not create short circuits).

Based on the images from the linked answer, it looks like both your motor and the similar one you refer to have 13 wires in the ribbon. Given that the pitch is fairly standardized for these types of cables, it's likely that they're the same, except maybe for length.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Yes the ribbons are the same except for the length. And since there is not much space to squeeze the extra length I wanted to buy a replacement motor with the exact same ribbon.
I could solder the old one on the new motor but as you can see in the picture it looks a little tricky to get to the far right with a solder iron.
But since I cannot find it online, I'll try my best to use the old ribbon.